# How to create a ANTD progress bar like a meter

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css, antd, vite

I want to create a progress bar like this using antd library to show the percentage value from an API

[image: I want to create a progress bar like this using antd library to show the presentage value from an API]

I design the progress bar like this, but when I apply the stroke color transparent but it shows the normal progress bar instead of showing the relative div like this
[image]

when I add a color to it, it shows the added color

[image]

below is my code

```
 <div className="w-full mt-2">
    <div className="flex flex-row relative">
      <div className="w-full py-2 bg-sliderGreenS rounded-l-lg"></div>
      <div className="w-full py-2 bg-sliderYellowS rounded-l-lg -ml-3"></div>
      <div className="w-full py-2 bg-sliderOrangeS rounded-l-lg -ml-3"></div>
      <div className="w-full py-2 bg-sliderRedS rounded-lg -ml-3"></div>

      <Progress
        className="w-full absolute -mt-1.5"
        percent={100}
        showInfo={false}
        strokeWidth={17}
        success={{
          percent: x,
          strokeColor: "transparent",
        }}
        strokeColor="rgba(0,0,0,0.5)"
      />
    </div>
```

I want to change it to the 1st attached picture. Am using tailwinds and ANTD package for this

Answer (score 0):

After some work, I came up with an answer, instead of using the progress bar from ANTD I used some custom divs to make the view using absolute and relative behavior.

```
<div className="w-full mt-2">
    <div className="flex flex-row relative">
      <div className="w-full py-2 bg-sliderGreenS rounded-l-lg"></div>
      <div className="w-full py-2 bg-sliderYellowS rounded-l-lg -ml-3"></div>
      <div className="w-full py-2 bg-sliderOrangeS rounded-l-lg -ml-3"></div>
      <div className="w-full py-2 bg-sliderRedS rounded-lg -ml-3"></div>
      <div
        className={`bg-[rgba(0,0,0,0.8)] absolute right-0 z-10 py-2 ${
          value >= 1 ? "rounded-r-lg" : "rounded-lg"
        } text-end`}
        style={{
          width: `${(100 - value)}%`,
        }}
      ></div>
    </div>
    <div
      className={`${value ===0 ? "text-start -pl-5" : "text-end"}`}
      style={{
        width: `${value===100? value : value+2}%`,
      }}
    >
      <div class="pt-2 flex justify-end">
        <div className="triangle-up"></div>
      </div>
      <div className={`text-sm`}>
      {value}
      </div>
    
    </div>
  </div>
```

value is the amount I want to show as the percentage.

The final result is like this

[image]